# How can you inject a session reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, structuremap, inject

Can you inject a session reference into your class via structure map

Comment: What's the programming language? What's the context, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you are referring to the HTTP Session for the current user, try adding this to your container registration code:

```
For<HttpSessionStateBase>().TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(() => new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session));
```

Now any class retrieved via StructureMap that takes an HttpSessionStateBase as one of its constructor parameters should get the current session.